# Replicating Portfolio 3-Period

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I have a 3-period model; where $\beta_t$ is the value the savings account.

The stock prices $S_t$ are given by $S_1=\xi_1$ , $S_2=\xi_1\xi_2$ and $S_3=\xi_1\xi_2\xi_3$.Where $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3$ are independent RV and take values {u,d} ie (up price movement, down price movement).

I have been given $H_3 = S_1 e^{S_2}$ is the price of a claim at time t = 3 and I need to prove the replicating portfolio is $(a_3,b_3)=(0,{H_3}/\beta^{3})$ and then find the price at time 2.

But I'm confused as to how to go about creating a replicating portfolio which would match this payout to discount it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your notation, what are $a_3,b_3$? Also, is $H_3$ the payout of the claim at time $t=3$?

Comment: $a_3$ and $b_3$ are the proportion on the overall portfolio in stock and bonds. Value of Portfolio at t = $a_t$* Stock Price t and $b_t$ Bond Return t (or any riskless asset). 
and yes $H_3$ is the payout expected at time 3. Originally we solved a one-step using a Martingale approach but Im notsure about converting that to a 3-step and the the exponential in there.

Comment: You just have thre one step problems. Work backwards. First determine the specific payout a each of the four states 3u, 2u1d, 2d1u, or 3d. Then, as of $t=2$, think of the replicating portfolios for each of the three nodes of the tree 2u, 1u1d, 2d. Once you have that, you repeat for the two nodes at t=1, 1u, 1d.